# Redshift - Filter multiple Not in condition

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to build a query that filters out any email that has gmail or yahoo in the name. I tried the below:

```
select email from users where email not like ('@gmail.com','@yahoo.com')
```

I get an error

```
ERROR - operator does not exist: character varying
```

I am using Redshift DB. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where email not like '%@gmail.com'
and email not like '%@yahoo.com'
```

there is no combination of a list with `like`, it works only for exact matches (`in`), and don't forget the wildcard (`%`)

if the list is larger there is another solution with a given answer (can look it up here if so)